# Why is hash of nan zero?

Tags: python, hash, nan

I would have thought

```
>>> hash(0)
0
>>> import math
>>> hash(math.nan)
0
```

would lead to frequent hash collisions. Why are they both hashed to zero?

Comment: What value would you have preferred other than 0?

Comment: This is *one* collision, not lots.

Comment: I meant frequent not lots, corrected

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen i've no idea. I'm trying to implement hash for Double in another language so looked to python

Comment: "would lead to frequent hash collisions" Unless you are using it as a placeholder in a Pandas Dataframe, `nan` is a pretty unusual value in normal Python programs.

Comment: note, you can just use `float('nan')`

Comment: @KarlKnechtel true, I'd forgotten python doesn't nan 0/0 like the language I'm used to working in

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen actually I'd thought that, suppose `hash` outputs a 64-bit value and takes a 64-bit value, there will be a unique representation for nan. I realise that assumes widths that may not be applicable here

Comment: I dare say it's relatively unusual to attempt the `0/0` computation anyway. Well written code will ordinarily avoid the situation naturally.

Comment: Anyway, what exactly do you mean by "why"? Are you looking for the specific code responsible? An authoritative statement of reasoning from the dev team? Something else?

Comment: (I think this is actually a bug, although the intended behavior is even further from what your intuition might suggest - it's *supposed* to delegate to `object.__hash__` for this case, so hashing NaN isn't even supposed to give a consistent value at all.)

Comment: Wait, no, that's a version difference. The `object.__hash__` delegation starts in 3.10.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel authoritative statement perhaps. Perhaps python-internals may be appropriate

Comment: @hobbs That's what I thought too, but actually, NaNs aren't equal to each other, so you can have multiple, e.g.: `{float('nan'): 0, float('nan'): 1}` -> `{nan: 0, nan: 1}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This behaviour has changed in Python 3.10](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.10.html#other-language-changes):

> - Hashes of NaN values of both [`float`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#float) type and [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html#decimal.Decimal) type now depend on object identity. Formerly, they always hashed to `0` even though NaN values are not equal to one another. This caused potentially quadratic runtime behavior due to excessive hash collisions when creating dictionaries and sets containing multiple NaNs. (Contributed by Raymond Hettinger in [bpo-43475](https://bugs.python.org/issue43475).)